# Flex Pixel Blender Performance

Tags: apache-flex, performance, pixel-bender

I remember seeing some articles about using Pixel Blender to speed up performance on heavy computation, but i cant find them anymore.  Can anyone suggest an article on this?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_pixelbender.html